# mongoose set a default field to take value of 2 other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to let one field take value of two other fields merged as default.
I have a user schema as follows:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },});
```

I want to add a third field called fullName that defaults to merging `firstName` + `lastName`
Is that possible in mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
 fullName:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    default: function(){
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }}
```

on doc update :

```
yourSchema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {

  this.set({ fullName: this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName")  });

  next();
});
```

Comment: this works if firstName and lastName are available on creation. but will not work for updates. Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

Comment: for updates you need to use pre update/updateOne hook, i edited my answer check it up

Comment: nice one i didnt know you have access to the document in the pre update but i see how you used get and set for that. thx

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using Virtual Setters (Virtuals) as [documented](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) by Mongoose

Make sure to add this to your Schema to include virtuals when you convert a document to JSON

```
const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };
```